# Chiffon cake deflating

Tags: baking

I'm currently on a chiffon-making spree but all my chiffon cakes keep on collapsing after cooling.

Here's the recipe I used:
- 100g flour
- 100g sugar, 50g for meringue and 50g for yolks
- 1 tsp baking powder (4g)
- 45g oil
- 90g water
- 3 eggs, separated

1) Preheat oven to 160C. Line bottom of 20cm cake pan with parchment paper (yes, not a chiffon cake pan; the original recipe called for a normal cake pan and reviewers have been successful with it). Sift together flour and baking powder, set aside.

2) Beat egg yolks and 50g sugar till thick and pale. Add in oil then whip till emulsified and thick. Add in water then mix till combined. Sift in flour mixture then mix till smooth. Set aside.

3) Beat egg whites with 50g sugar till firm peak stage. Fold into egg yolk mixture in 3 batches, banging the bowl occasionally to remove any big air bubbles.

4) Pour batter slowly, and a from a height, into prepared cake pan. Bake for 60 minutes. Once done, cool inverted.

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

**the cake also kind of deflated in the oven at around 45 minute mark. It had a slight dome that evened out.

Thanks in advance for all help!

edit: could it be the liquid flour ratio that is causing my cakes to collapse? I remember reading somewhere that if you have too much liquid, the cake once cooled will collapse under its own weight. But I sort of don't think this is the case since most of the liquid in this recipe is water; which almost all would evaporate during baking.